# Overlapping percentages in Likert bar plot in R

Tags: r, likert

I have successfully obtained a divergent stacked bar plot using the likert package for survey data. However one of the questions (S8) has overlapping percentages:[Overlapping percentages in S8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWutX.png)

I have tried using the zero.print = TRUE option to remove the 0% and to make the graph clearer without overlapping percentages, but in this case, the zeros disappear but the percentage symbol remains:
[Plot using the zero.print=TRUE option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4OlO.png)

How can I fix this overlapping issue? Is there a solution using ggplot addition to the likert function? Alternatively, If I use the zero.print option can I remove the percent symbol?